# How do you handle the singularity in polar or cylindrical coordinates?

Tags: pde, finite-difference, numerical-modelling, coordinate-transform

Governing equations in polar or cylindrical coordinates often have terms with $\frac{1}{r}$ involved. At $r = 0$, such terms blow up to become a "singularity." The Cartesian version of such governing equations will not have these "singularities" at $(x,y)=(0,0)$. Therefore, the singularity at $r = 0$ must be numerical.

**How do you handle the singularity at $r = 0$ in polar or cylindrical coordinates via e.g., finite difference?**

To break this down:

- How are the radial coordinates discretized and differentiated?
- Is there is a transformation of variables of $(r,\theta)$ involved?
- How does any of this prevent blow-up at $r = 0$?

Let's assume the general case where there is no (anti-) symmetry to exploit and the governing equations rely on $r$ and $\theta$ explicitly, so the polar problem is at least two-dimensional. The governing partial differential equations could be the heat equation, Navier-Stokes equations, or Laplace's equation.

Some related answers are:

[Neumann Boundary Condition at r=0 in Polar Coordinates (Numerical BCs)](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/17478/neumann-boundary-condition-at-r-0-in-polar-coordinates-numerical-bcs)

[Finite difference methods in cylindrical and spherical co-ordinate systems](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/35248/finite-difference-methods-in-cylindrical-and-spherical-co-ordinate-systems)

Comment: Using some small nonzero $r_{min}$ instead of $r=0$ is an easy solution acceptable for many applications.

Comment: So, the radial mesh would be something like {$r_{min}$, $r_{min} +\Delta r$, $+ ...$, $+ r_{max}$} or would it be something like {$-r_{max}$, $+...$, $-r_{min}$, $r_{min}$, $+ ...$, $+ r_{max}$}? 

If it is the former, does $r_{min}$ require a "boundary" condition? What would that be? 

If it is the latter, is there a transformation of variables involved (I'm thinking of needing to change the definition of $\theta$)?

Comment: [A related question on Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/774332/64206)

Comment: One could use the grid, e.g., $\epsilon, \Delta r, 2 \Delta r, ..., r_{max}$. At $r_{min}=\epsilon$ the boundary condition would enforce Dirichlet or Neumann (or more complex) conditions that you'd use with $r_{min}$=0.

Comment: The problem you're having is called the "coordinate singularity" and is, among other places, addressed in this paper https://doi.org/10.1006/jcph.1999.6382

Comment: @SpencerBryngelson
This suggests that you perform a transformation of variables such that $(r, \theta) \rightarrow (\tilde{r}, \tilde{\theta})$ so that the physical governing equations defined on $r\in [0, r_{max}]$, $\theta \in [0, 2\pi)$ become $\tilde{r} \in [-r_{max}, +r_{max}]$ and $\tilde{\theta} \in [0, \pi)$. The radial mesh must not include the $r = 0$ point exactly. The radial derivatives would be $\frac{\partial}{\partial r} = f(\theta) \frac{\partial}{\partial \tilde{r}}$ where $f(\theta) = +1$ if $0 \leq \theta < \pi$ and $f(\theta) = -1$ if $\pi \leq \theta < 2 \pi$.

Comment: @MaximUmansky I think "boundary" conditions at $\epsilon$ could be generally derived or otherwise empirically imposed for axisymmetric problems (i.e., you could neglect variation in $\theta$ and therefore this becomes a one-dimensional problem). How would "boundary" conditions be derived for two-dimensional problems that feature more than one dependent variable e.g., $f(r,\theta)$ and $g(r,\theta)$?

Comment: @SpencerBryngelson This method is interesting; would I be able to edit the original question to explicitly elucidate the Navier-Stokes equations treated with this method or would that more typically belong in a new answer?

Comment: @Steve M For a small $\epsilon$, there is no dependence on $\theta$ in the boundary conditions imposed there because all points on the circle $r=\epsilon$ are physically very close to each other.

Answer (score 5):

Let me show this specifically for the finite element discretization of the Laplace equation:
$$
  -\frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial}{\partial r} \left(r \frac{\partial}{\partial r} u(r,\theta)\right)
 - \frac{1}{r^2} \frac{\partial^2}{\partial \theta^2} u(r,\theta)
 = f(r,\theta).
$$
The finite element method is based on the weak formulation, which you obtain by multiplying the equation by a test function $\varphi(r,\theta)$ and integrating over the domain, then integrate by parts. You'd think that that leads to
$$
  \int_0^R \int_0^{2\pi}
  \varphi(r,\theta)
  \left[
  -\frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial}{\partial r} \left(r \frac{\partial}{\partial r} u(r,\theta)\right)
 - \frac{1}{r^2} \frac{\partial^2}{\partial \theta^2} u(r,\theta)
 \right]
   \, d\theta dr
 = \int_0^R \int_0^{2\pi} \varphi(r,\theta) f(r,\theta) \, d\theta dr,
$$
followed by integration by parts.

But you don't have to do it that way -- the above approach simply assumes that $r$ and $\theta$ are independent variables. Instead, you use the *proper* area element, which is $2\pi r \, dr \, d\theta$ and you get the following form instead:
$$
  \int_0^R \int_0^{2\pi}
  \varphi(r,\theta)
  \left[
  -\frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial}{\partial r} \left(r \frac{\partial}{\partial r} u(r,\theta)\right)
 - \frac{1}{r^2} \frac{\partial^2}{\partial \theta^2} u(r,\theta)
 \right]
   \, 2\pi r \, d\theta dr
\\
 = \int_0^R \int_0^{2\pi} \varphi(r,\theta) f(r,\theta) \, 2\pi r \, d\theta dr.
$$
The $2\pi$ cancel on the two sides, and so what you have left is this:
$$
  \int_0^R \int_0^{2\pi}
  \varphi(r,\theta)
  \left[
  -\frac{\partial}{\partial r} \left(r \frac{\partial}{\partial r} u(r,\theta)\right)
 - \frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial^2}{\partial \theta^2} u(r,\theta)
 \right]
   \, d\theta dr
 = \int_0^R \int_0^{2\pi} \varphi(r,\theta) f(r,\theta) \, r \, d\theta dr.
$$
After integration by parts, you then have the following (omitting boundary terms for simplicity):
$$
  \int_0^R \int_0^{2\pi}
  r \frac{\partial \varphi(r,\theta)}{\partial r}
     \frac{\partial u(r,\theta)}{\partial r}
 + \frac{1}{r} 
   \frac{\partial \varphi(r,\theta)}{\partial \theta}
   \frac{\partial u(r,\theta)}{\partial \theta}
   \, d\theta dr
 = \int_0^R \int_0^{2\pi} \varphi(r,\theta) f(r,\theta) \, r \, d\theta dr.
$$
As you can see, at least from in front of the the $r$ derivatives, the singular weight has disappeared. If you choose appropriate quadrature rules, then the quadrature points for the second term will never lie at $r=0$, and so the still singular weight will not matter in the $\theta$-derivative term.

Comment: How will the $1/r$ singular weight be made irrelevant after integration?

To generalize, the method to treat the singularity is to somehow remove the $r = 0$ meshpoint from consideration?

Comment: I've never seen things done this way before. Could you point me to what a "proper" area element is? It seems to be what you'd get when you transform $dx dy$ into polar.

Comment: @Nachiket Yes, exactly. It's just a coordinate transform. The integral is over a domain in $R^2$, and the integral should be the same whether you express it in $x-y$ coordinates or $r-\theta$ coordinates. The area element that includes the factor $2\pi r$ does that.

Comment: @SteveM We can't compute integrals in practice. We have to use quadrature. The question is what quadrature formula you choose.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth What bothers me is that you seem to get two different weak forms. The first one when you treat $r$ and $\theta$ as independent and a different, more nicer form, when you use the 'proper area element' approach.

Comment: That's no different from any other equation. You can always include a weight function into your integral of the weak form, and get different weak formulations of the PDE. That then just leads to existence theories in different function spaces (these function spaces differ by their weights).

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth So effectively you're just changing the weighting function from $\varphi(r,\theta)$ to $r\varphi(r,\theta)$?

Comment: @Nachiket That's maybe not quite the right way to look at it from a conceptual point, but the effect is the same, yes.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth Continuing the same line of thought, I presume it's also possible to change $ \varphi(r,\theta)\rightarrow r^2\varphi(r,\theta)$ in order to get rid of the $\frac{1}{r^2}$ in front of the $\theta$ derivatives.

Comment: @Nachiket You can, but the question is whether you are able to integrate the other part by parts in a convenient way so that the resulting bilinear form becomes symmetric and positive definite. You will have noticed that that is the case with the $2\pi r$ weight but that that would not have been the case when using no weight at all.